# node js script to act upon a constellation response

Tags: javascript, node.js

H Apologies,

This is going to be an incredibly beginner question - I have been trying to figure this out on my own this afternoon. I am only beginning coding in js for the first time today.

I am trying to create a script that will monitor Mixer's constellation server, receive a response when a stream goes live. (I have this bit working fine and when the streamer goes online it send a true message, when the streamer goes offline i get false).

```
    const Carina = require('carina').Carina;
    const ws = require('ws');

    Carina.WebSocket = ws;

    const channelId = xxxxxx;
    const ca = new Carina({ isBot: true }).open();
    ca.subscribe(`channel:${channelId}:update`, data => {
    console.log(data.online);
    });
```

I then would like it to trigger a POST query to using the maker script part of IFTTT to trigger an event there (such as flash my lights when my favourite streamer goes online) - I also have this script working fine!

```
    var request = require("request");

    request({
    uri: 
"https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/streaming/with/key/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    method: "POST",
    }, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
    });
```

Problem I have, is I have zero knowledge of js, as to have to merge the 2 together, so that when I receive a 'true' response from the Mixer constellation server, it runs the second part of the script.

I hope that you go easy on my lack of knowledge and I look thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have to simply use a function in callback of another function like this:

```
        const Carina = require('carina').Carina;
        const ws = require('ws');

        Carina.WebSocket = ws;

        const channelId = xxxxxx;
        const ca = new Carina({ isBot: true }).open();
        var request = require("request");

        ca.subscribe(`channel:${channelId}:update`, data => {
        if(data.online){
          request({
             uri: 

  "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/streaming/with/key/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            method: "POST",
            }, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log(body);
            });
}              

            });
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, I did one little tweak to the code with the if statement, due to how the Mixer constellation server returned the true value when a streamers went Online :D
         if(data.online == true){

Comment: its equal to `if(data.online)` with a little difference which is type checking for `undefined` value and `null` value @RasmusKristensen